# Use a Criteria on top of another Criteria

Tags: c#, java, nhibernate, hibernate, activerecord

I have a question on criteria: 
How can i use a Criteria (or similar) that filters and/or do whatever with another criteria?

Something like:

select clients.* from
    (select * from clients) as clients

The real problem is something else, but achieving this behaviour would be terrific...

(btw, both java and .net are welcome to help)

thanks

Comment: Why don't you post the real problem? A general solution wouldn't necessarily be the best for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done, AFAIK. The [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries) about HQL says:

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

I can't find same statement about Criteria, but in API the only way to create criteria is to give mapped type. There is support for subqueries but only in where clause. [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries) is javadoc.

Comment: In fact, the thing was that I wanted to use it on the FROM clause, like a result set, such as with (tsql).

Answer (score 1):

Your FROM clause needs to be a mapped object.  You could do a subselect inside the WHERE clause... something like:

```
select c from clients c where c.id in (select c2.id from clients c2)
```

It would help if you could give a better example.  The example you gave can be reduced down to the following HQL:

```
"from clients"
```

...which isn't terribly useful.

Comment: lol, thank you. My problem is that this is a quite hard query to put on nhibernate common standarts...
Perhaps i need to study a little more, to come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a `NHibernate.Criterion.InExpression` to your criteria.

Found an example on this blog:
http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/08/26/parameter-lists-in-nhibernate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand your question correctly, but if you want to do a select on a list of objects, you can use the subqueries with *DetachedCriteria*. I use it all the time, especially for paging objects while creating a left outer join, which could lead me to incorrect number of entities.

Imagine you've got users who buy products, with a relationship many-many:

Dim dc As DetachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For(GetType(User)).SetFirstResult(pageNumber * itemsPerPage).SetMaxResults(itemsPerPage)
Session.CreateCriteria(GetType(user)).Add(**Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", dc)**).CreateAlias("ProductsBought", "pb", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)

Thom's right, perhaps you should be more precise...

Comment: Hibernate supports subqueries in SELECT and WHERE caluse. The OP is about subquery in FROM clause. It can't be done AFAIK.